# How to dispatch multiple actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch functions from reducer but it call only one function.

Reducer looks like this:

```
import types from "./types";

const initState = {
  active: false,
  myData: []
};

function toggleActive(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    active: action.payload
  };
}

function watchInfo(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    myData: action.payload
  };
}

const watchReducer = (state = initState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case types.TOGGLE_ACTIVE:
      return toggleActive(state, action);
    case types.WATCH_DATA:
      return watchInfo(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default watchReducer;
```

and action creator is set like this:

```
import types from "./types";

function toggleActive(bool) {
  return {
    type: types.TOGGLE_ACTIVE,
    payload: bool
  };
}

function watchInfo(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.WATCH_DATA,
      payload: data
    });
  };
}

export { toggleActive as default, watchInfo };
```

and in component in which I am importing connect and corresponding action creator, i am trying to use it like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  watchInfo: () => dispatch(watchInfo())
});

export default connect
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

So when I inspect in redux console it only calls toggleActive, never calls watch info.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this action creator

```
function watchInfo(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.WATCH_DATA,
      payload: data
    });
  };
}
```

to:

```
function watchInfo(data) {
  return {
      type: types.WATCH_DATA,
      payload: data
    }
}
```

action creator is a function that return an object that representing an action. we use action creators for better code maintenance and prevent some Spelling error but this code:

```
dispatch(watchInfo(someData))
```

is equivalent to this:

```
dispatch({
          type: types.WATCH_DATA,
          payload: someData
        })
```

Comment: I did the change but it never calls the watchInfo() function. If i put console log in reducer, it just calls TOGGLE_ACTIVE, not WATCH_DATA. in my component I use it like this:
` const MyComponent = ({ watchInfo }) `

Comment: @youngster when you map dispatch to props then you can dispatch or fire those actions by props. for example:
this.props.watchInfo() or this.props.toggleActive(). because those actions  are mapped to props object.

Comment: Can you show me how you dispatch actions in components code?

Comment: sure. I think that is the problem, probably I am not exporting it right.

i action creator Im exporting like this: 

````
export { toggleActive as default, watchInfo };
```

and in component like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  
  watchInfo : data=> dispatch(watchInfo (data))
});
```

Comment: ok you can import it like this: -> 
import toggleActive , {watchInfo } from "./forExampleActionCreators"
  if you export it like this: ->  export { toggleActive as default, watchInfo }